# How to schedule Cron Job in Linux

Tags: python, linux, cron

I've scheduled a Cron job like below but it is not executing. Do I need to put command before or is it ok to write only path.

1. With Command in the cronjob: `0 4 * * 1 python /app/www/html/RegionSubregion/ceeinca.py`
2. Without command in the cronjob: `0 4 * * 1 /app/www/html/RegionSubregion/ceeinca.py`

Which one is correct here?
I need to run this particular python script on 1st day (Monday) of everyweek at 4AM. Please guide. Thank you.

Comment: If your python script works fine, then maybe you should try at least to run it with the full path to python. `$PATH` may not be the same as the one of your regular user. Other solution: set `$PATH` at start of your crontab.

Comment: Thanks, python script works and with full path it works. But it's not working in cron job. I need to know if the option 1 is correct or option 2?

Comment: I mean full path to python executable, like for instance: `0 4 * * 1 /usr/bin/python /app/www/html/RegionSubregion/ceeinca.py`. Using `python` or `/usr/bin/python`, or not, before your python script, is up to you: you may `chmod` it executable and start your `ceeinca.py` by something like `#!/usr/bin/env python` (maybe also with full path to python?) or let it without this first line, not executable and run it via python.

Comment: You want option 1. You need to either set the `PATH` properly in your `crontab` so that it contains the location of `python`, or, for option 1, specify the whole path to `python` as mentioned already.

Comment: first: you should try it few times (so put the job near NOW), and test which of the two works, than you can change the time. Normally we put an `activate...` before to call python. This is important if the main python doesn't have all modules.

Comment: I suggest you to use `0 4 * * 1 /app/www/html/RegionSubregion/ceeinca.py`

But, give to the script the correct permissions: `chmod +x /app/www/html/RegionSubregion/ceeinca.py`

And consider that crond does not have any environment variable when launching a job.
So if your script is expecting some environment variable like `PYTHONPATH`, I'm pretty sure it won't be initialized, you should do by your own inside the script.

I use to add all the environment variables inside my scripts to be sure it run without problems.

Comment: Thank you all. After giving execute permission to file it's working fine with option 2. Thank you all for you support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 works if you give execute permission to the file.

Execute Permission: `chmod +x /app/www/html/RegionSubregion/ceeinca.py`